# How to obtained the json from the dataframe with the column names for every row as a key using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want the json data from the dataframe where  I need to have the column name as key for every row using python.

```
Name   Age  Qualification
  A     35     MCA
  B     30     Phd
  C     28     Msc
```

From the above dataframe I want the json. I don't want to convert it into dictionary. it should row-wise json data. How to get the json in the below format?

```
{'Name': 'A' , 'Age': 35 , 'Qualification':'MCA'}
{'Name': 'B' , 'Age': 30 , 'Qualification':'Phd'}
{'Name': 'C' , 'Age': 28 , 'Qualification':'Msc'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json_str_list = [] 
for i in df.index:
    json_str = df.loc[i].to_json()
    json_str_list.append(json_str)
```

The above code will solve your question.  If you want it to be a JSON object you can import json and just do,

```
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) with parameters `orient='records'` and `lines=True`:

```
df.to_json(file, orient='records', lines=True)
```